# Boundedness of Integral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities

Suppose we operate on the unit simplex $\Delta \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ with $0$ as a corner point.

Define the integral

$$
Iu(x):=\int_0^1 t^{|\beta|-1}x^\beta u(tx)\mathrm{d}t,\quad x\in \Delta
$$
and $\beta \in \mathbb{N}^d$ a multiindex.

**Question:** Do we have the inequality
\begin{equation}
\left\|\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i } Iu \right\| \le C \|u\\|
\end{equation}
for some constant $C>0$ and $\|\cdot \|$ meaning the $L^2(\Delta)$-norm?

The integral $I$ arises for instance as remainder term in a Taylor expansion. I found (1) easy to prove for $d=1$ (simply substitute $\tau = tx$), for higher dimensions I tried polar coordinates but to no avail.

**Edit** My guess is that the answer is no, since $I$ only smoothes along rays emanating from zero...

Comment: Could you edit the tex? Is $u$ an arbitrary $L^2$ function?

Comment: I edited the tex. There seems to be something wrong with the interpreter. Yes, $u$ can be arbitrary in $L^2$.

Comment: Your suspicion is right, take any function which depends only on $x/|x|$, it comes out of the integral

Comment: yes, sorry for the stupid question...